# Is it possible to breed pets in the sims 2?

Tags: the-sims-2

This was something that had always been stuck in my head. can you breed them? and if so how do you due to the lack of being able to control them unless you use the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can breed pets in the sims 2. See http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Breeding#The_Sims_2:_Pets

> In The Sims 2: Pets, a pet house is required. This allows the player to have the selected Sim command a pet to try to have puppies/kittens with another pet. The Sim must have a good relationship with the selected pet to successfully command it. Additionally, the two pets must also have a good relationship with one another. If successful, the two pets will go into a pet house and WooHoo. If the female pet becomes pregnant, the player will hear the same music that plays when a Sim conceives.

If you do want to control the pets yourself, you can use the cheat `boolProp controlPets on` after opening the cheat console with `control-shift-C`.